# Problem with jquery slidedown div size

Tags: jquery, html, size, slidedown

I wanted to see if anyone has any suggestions on how to fix this. I am working on this website and I am trying to make a jquery downward slider extend over the whole page. I'm not sure how well I can explain in word so please take a look at the example here:
[Slide down example](http://www.johnfitzphoto.com/sofi/new_stuff/index.html)
So if you take a look and press on the first portfolio piece it slides down however I was only able to make it as big as the div size would let me (200px). I want for it to extend through the whole page so I can put information there. Also if I apply it to all the next portfolio buttons, it also extends all the way. I tried to take the hidden slider out from the image div but then It would open on the right and all the other buttons would move down.

Any suggestions?
Thanks guys.
Sophie

Comment: You don't need to add a signature to your posts. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Answer (score 0):

I just reorganized the html code and put the slider at the end of the first line of portfolio images. Made it float left and the correct size while adding at the top:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

So I it didn't follow the previous style from the top images div.

Hope I made myself clear but if anyone has more questions on how I solved it and would like to use this code, let me know!

Thanks
Sophie.